# Create a pulse of a given signal

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fpga

I have a signal `sig`. This may remain high for multiple clock cycles. I want to create a pulse of it that should toggle for as many clock cycles for which the signal was high.

That is every time my signal sig goes from low to high, I will get a pulse of it.
The challenging thing is if the signal is high for multiple clk, how will I create a pulse of it?
Even though my signal is high for three consecutive clock cycles, my pulse should toggle three times (from 0 to 1 and 1 to 0).

```
module PULSE_GEN  (input clk,  input sig,input en,output wire pulse);

reg r1,r2,r3;
        always @(posedge clk) begin
           if(en)
           begin
             r1 =sig;
             r2 = r1 ^ sig; 
             r3 = r1 & r2;
           end
           else
             r3 = 1'b0;
        end 

assign pulse =  r3; 

endmodule
```

However, I am not able to generate the pulse. The waveform in the order shows `pulse`, `en`, `sig` and `clk`. `pulse` is always low.

[image]

I created a drawing of a desired waveform:

[image]

As the image shows ,sig is higher for multiple clock cycles.The requirement is that the pulse should become high on the posedge of clk and should become low on next posedge of the clk. And Again becomes high on next posedge as sig was high. This should happen only when en condition is high(which is basically Time advance).If en is low ,pulse should be low.

Comment: they are in the order pulse,en,sig and clk

Comment: `r1 ^ sig` will always be 0 because `r1 = sig`.  Your description has a contradiction in that you say you _want to create a pulse of it on a particular clk which should remain high only for one clock cycle_, but then you say you want _it to toggle three times_.

Comment: @Mikef: i created a drawing

Comment: @mikef: whenever my sig is high,my pulse should become high on the posedge of the clock and should go down on the next posedge of the clk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you require `pulse` to rise with `sig` means you need to use Mealy style state machine; where the output is a function of its present state and current input. Mealy is fast, but is more susceptible to glitches and other limitation. I recommend searching: *Mealy vs Moore*. I also recommend searching about *Verilog blocking vs non-blocking*

Your required behavior can be achieved with the below. I omitted the `en` as your question looks like homework. I will leave it to you to figure out.

```
assign pulse = !present_state && sig;
always @(posedge clk) begin
  present_state <= pulse && sig;
end
```

[image]